# Fill dropdown list from database in create view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I fetch and insert data at a specific time in one view in mvc razor view? I mean to fill a dropdown list from the database in create view.

I want to fill the following when I add the subject and cheater models.

- department list
- semester list
- standard list
- stream list

**cheater model:**

```
namespace firstapp.Models
{
  public class chepter
  {
      [ForeignKey("dip_id")]
      public int dipart_id { get; set; }
      public int chep_id { get; set; }
      public string subject { get; set; }
      public string chepter { get; set; }
      public List<dipartment> dipartlist { get; set; }
      public List<dipartment> stdlist { get; set; }
      public List<dipartment> semlist { get; set; }
      public List<dipartment> stremlist { get; set; } 
   }
}
```

**department model:**

```
namespace firstapp.Models
{
   public class dipartment 
   {        
      public int dip_id { get; set; }
      public string dipart { get; set; }
      public string std { get; set; }
      public string sem { get; set; }
      public string strem { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try this [Dynamically_Populating_Dropdown_Based_On_Other_Dropdown_Value](http://jweavers.com/posts/Dynamically_Populating_Dropdown_Based_On_Other_Dropdown_Value_In_Java.php)

Comment: this is java ........not mvc please give me ans in mvc..........

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dipart_id, new SelectList(Model.dipartlist.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Value = s.dip_id, Selected = false, Text = s.dipart })), "Select")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your model so the list property is a selectlist:

```
public SelectList<dipartment> dipartlist { get; set; }
```

Then, when you populate the model call a service class method(you might not have a service layer, I just prefer to not have database calls in the controller)

```
dipartlist = _departmentService.GetAsSelectList();
```

The `GetAsSelectList` service method looks like this:

```
public SelectList GetAsSelectList()
{
    return (from d in _context.Set<department>().OrderBy(x => x.dipart)
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = d.dipart_id,
                        Name = d.dipart
                    }).ToList();
}
```

And finally your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dipart_id, Model.dipartlist)
```

This technique means you don't have linq in either the view or controller. Also as you're only creating the selectlist in one place (the service), you can cache it with [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) to prevent multiple requests for the same data. And as it looks like you're populating 4 selectlists, this might be useful.

Comment: :Thanx to take interest my question and for your suggestion. But VS showing me red underline to selectlist. What should i do for this??                                                                                                 public SelectList<dipartment> dipartlist { get; set; }

Comment: You need to add `using System.Web.Mvc;` at the top of the file

Comment: continue  this problem  after i use this name space ........vs is show me read underline